# Lite mode in browser on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I mostly read a lot on web. I badly need browser with lite mode because recently I got my machine terribly slowed down frequently. I checked windows task manager and chrome task manager and found that chrome and some of its web pages / tabs very hogging RAM. I read that Chrome has lite mode. But thats restricted for mobiles, not [PCs](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=1). How can I have chrome load lite pages. Or is there any browser which will do the same?

Comment: Just reduce the number of tabs you use.  Chrome and other browsers use RAM for each tab. There is no big problem in using RAM.

Comment: if I can do that I would have already done that...I have 16 GB RAM on personal laptop. So I have habit of keeping several tabs open for multi tasking. Office machine has lesser RAM, so it gets stuck.

Comment: If the computer is slowing down, it is not likely a RAM issue. Using RAM does not slow a CPU. Check for viruses (Windows Defender). Run MSCONFIG, boot tab, do a clean boot and then add processes / services looking for the process or service that is causing this

Comment: @John It will slow down when it is close to running out of memory as the OS spends all of it's time trying to swap to disk ...

Comment: Also long as memory is living within its limits, using it does not slow down my CPU. Never has in years of doing this.

Comment: what about: `hh.exe http://www.google.com`

Comment: @HelpingHand can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Well hh..exe is the Windows help file viewer. It just so happens that you can pass it a url and it will embed I guess the IE control to render the page. It might be an option as a light weight browser.

Comment: but thats just single page viewer. I just tried. It was showing javascript warnings. Also I use tabs and extensions a lot. Cant live without them.